# When should a DB table be split into two separate ones?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a users table, which employs single table inheritance, so that I can have both Consultants, Clients, and Internal Users all within the same table.  I want to create a table for "notes", so that internal users can make notes on clients and consultants.  I'm not sure if I should create a consultants_notes and a clients_notes table, or just create a single notes table?  What factors should I consider?

Comment: You said `internal users can make notes on clients and consultants`, does that mean that a note has to have an InternalUserId and a ClientUserId OR ConsultantUserId? This means, two fields per NOTE

Comment: A note would have an internal_user_id, and a subject_user_id (either clientUserId or consultantUserId).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said in a comment:

> I'm not really sure yet how much the notes for each user type will differ, so I'd like to be able to keep it flexible, if possible

I think both ways (one or two tables) will be flexible enough. However, you should also consider [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If you then realize that a consultant requires the Date of the note and that the clients do not require that field, then you'll start getting lot's of null values on your table (**space**, as if a bit costs that much these days :P and lack of **normalization**).

So it might seem that a one table solution is a disadvantage. However, the one table solution will simplify your queries (**readability**) and also give you better performance (**speed**) because you won't have to make a join per each note table.

The advantages and disadvantages of the two table solution are actually the opposite to the ones of the one table. So, what are your main restrictions? If it is speed, you'll go for the one table solution. In my opinion I would go for the two table solution, because I can't stand having unnecesary values in a table. Besides, having a strict design, i.e. one that won't allow you to add a client note value to a consultant note value, is much safer than one that allow you to do that with a simple UPDATE. Although you can add restrictions to column values to come around this, it isn't the same.

Well, that's my humble opinion. Hope it helps, or at least makes you think twice before choosing your design :)

PS: The factors to consider are in **bold**

Answer (score 2):

I would start with one table:

- You already have just one table for any kind of user.
- There is no point in making three identical artifacts (and triple the code to use 3 tables).

However if each kind of note will differ a lot from the others you can consider which is better for you:
  * More tables with specific columns for each kind of note.
  * One universal table with some extra columns not always used.

Consider:

- How many notes will be stored in the table.
- What data will be stored for each kind of note.

Check how to build indexes to access specific kinds of notes and decide what is better for you.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not really sure yet how much the notes for each user type will differ, so I'd like to be able to keep it flexible, if possible. Will this be a problem with the one universal table?

Comment: I don't think so. You can always split notes table later -- just create new tables, move notes to new tables and release new version of product which uses new data structures. But for now -- use [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it).

Answer (score 2):

You have one table for three types of users so why have three tables for their notes?

The problem with three table for notes is that that you'll have to selectively look into one of these tables when you search for notes of a particular user. You'll end up hard coding this logic in your PHP code using if-else statements - or - you'll left join with three tables in your queries.

And what if you decide to have four types of users.

Answer (score 0):

I see you tagged `php` so unless you use two different pages to read/write notes for different user types I'd go for a single table because you don't need two separate queries.
Unless you expect to have thousands of notes in the table in which case seperate tables might be more efficient.